# js присвоить значение

Tags: javascript

Есть функция которая выдаёт цвет имени для пользователя:

```
var Arr = ['Red', 'Purple', 'Yellow', 'Green', 'Blue'];
var already = [];

function random() {
    var RandomArr = Math.floor(Math.random() * Arr.length);
    var random = Arr[RandomArr];
    Arr.splice(Arr.indexOf(random), 1);

    if () {

        return ;
    } else {
        already.push([name,random]);
        return random;
    }
}
```

После выдачи значение записывается в массив already , как сделать проверку на наличии name в массиве и при наличии выдачу присвоеного значени?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var nameToFind = "Андрей";
var found = already.find(function(item) { return item[0] == nameToFind; })
if (found)
  console.log(found[1]);
```

Comment: В already добавляется ["Андрей", "Yellow"], а из Arr удаляется Yellow, что бы не было повторов.

Comment: Довольно хардкодный код получился

Answer (score 1):

Поиск индекса подмассива по значению одного из его элементов (с известным индексом):

```
let foundIdx; 
let found = array.some((sub, i) => (foundIdx = i, sub[searchIdx] === searchVal));
```

Если метод вернет в переменную `found` истину, то в `foundIdx` будет индекс найденного элемента `array` (индекс *первого* подмассива, у которого значение по индексу `searchIdx` строго равно `searchVal`).

В данном выражении, вместо `some` можно написать `find` - результат останется прежним (`find()` работает быстрее, и с большими массивами лучше использовать именно его). Я использовал `some()` просто во избежание визуальной каши из имен:  "foundIdx, found, find".
Круглые скобки вокруг выражения коллбэка - это не ошибка: так определяем приоритет операций, чтобы выполнились оба выражения, и вернулся результат второго.

---

```js
var colors = ['Red', 'Purple', 'Yellow', 'Green', 'Blue'];
var already = [];

function randomColorFor(name) {
  const DEFAULT_COLOR = 'White'; 
  let colorIdx, color; 
  name = name.toLowerCase(); 
  if (!already.some((n, i) => (color = n[1], n[0] === name))) {
    if (colors.length) {
      colorIdx = Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length); 
      color = colors[colorIdx]; 
      colors.splice(colorIdx, 1); 
    }
    else 
      color = DEFAULT_COLOR; 
  }
  already.push([name, color]);
  return color; 
}

let names = ['Елена', 'Иван', 'Павел', 'Анна', 'Сергей', 'Ольга', 'Александр', 'ИВАН', 'анна']; 
let name, color; 
while (names.length) {
  color = randomColorFor(name = names.shift()); 
  document.body.innerHTML += `<span style="color: ${color}">${name}</span><br>`; 
}
console.log('Белый по-умолчанию: назначается когда цветов не хватило.');
```

```css
body {
  padding: 0 4px; 
  background-color: #ccc; 
  font: 14px sans-serif; 
}
```